# Within function how to correctly pass a parameter as a data attribute in R?

Tags: r

I want to write a function which returns a particular attribute of a data subject as follows

```
dem <- function(sale, attToCall = "year" ){
return(sale$attToCall)
}

aa <- data.frame("month" = sample(1:12, 10),"year" = sample(1990:2016, 10))

dem(aa, attToCall = "year")
```

doesn't work, anyone has solution?

Comment: You want to use `return(sale[[attToCall]])` in your function.

Comment: Thanks Imo for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
dem <- function(sale, attToCall = "year" ){
  return(sale[,attToCall])
}

aa <- data.frame("month" = sample(1:12, 10),"year" = sample(1990:2016, 10))

dem(aa, attToCall = "year")
```

> [1] 2012 2004 2010 2001 1995 2002 2015 2005 2009 1997